# error: assignment of read-only reference ‘__b’

Tags: c++, vector, swap

```
void customsort()
{
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    vector<pair<int, int> >::const_iterator it1,it2;
    for(it1 = temp.begin();it1<temp.end();it1++)
        for(it2 = temp.begin()+1;it2<temp.end();it2++)
            {
                a = it1->first+it1->second;
                b = it2->first+it2->second;     
                if(a>b)
                {   
                    swap(it1->first, it2->first);
                    swap(it1->second, it2->second);
                }
            }   
}
```

this is the code

what i am trying to do is swap a paired vector

for example

say i have a [1,1], [1,2], [2,0], [3,2]

i want to sort them based on their sum (ascending order)

BUT 
i am getting an error

> ```
> In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_algobase.h:64,
>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/char_traits.h:39,
>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ios:40,
>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/ostream:38,
>                  from /usr/include/c++/4.8/iostream:39,
>                  from prog1.cpp:1:
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = const int]’:
> prog1.cpp:23:34:   required from here
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:176:11: error: assignment of read-only reference ‘__a’
>        __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
>            ^
> /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/move.h:177:11: error: assignment of read-only reference ‘__b’
>        __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
> ```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `iterator` instead of a `const_iterator` for variables `it1` and `it2`.

It's not possible to change the values using `const_iterator` (and `swap` wants to change the values), that's why you are getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says:

```
In instantiation of ‘void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = const int]’:
```

i.e. it thinks you're trying to swap two `const int`s, which is not possible. The reason the `int`s are `const` is that you're using a `const_iterator` instead of an `iterator`.